# Expressão regular de citações no R

Tags: r, regex, grep

Gostaria de extrair todas as chaves de referência que uso em um documento *markdown* que começam com o caractere `@`.

Segue um exemplo das diferentes formas que posso citar um documento usando essa chave:

```
line <- 'According to @REF1, north American trees are lagging behind climate change [@REF2; @REF3]. However, some species have shown range limits expansion following warming temperature [*e.g.* white spruce @REF4; @REF5].'
```

A partir desse exemplo, gostaria de obter um vetor com as seguintes chaves:

```
citations
# [1] REF1
# [1] REF2
# [1] REF3
# [1] REF4
# [1] REF5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende do formato que essas citações podem ter. Uma opção seria:

```
str_extract_all(line, "(?<=@)\\w+")
```

Que retorna:

```
[1] "REF1" "REF2" "REF3" "REF4" "REF5"
```

Esta regex usa [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - o trecho entre `(?<=` e `)` - e serve para verificar se algo existe antes da posição atual. No caso, dentro do *lookbehind* só tem a `@`.

O detalhe é que a `@`, por estar em um *lookbehind*, não fará parte do *match*, então a regex só retornará o que está depois dela, que no caso é `\\w+`. O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` significa "letras, números ou o caractere `_`", e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências".

Na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420332/112052) foi sugerido usar `\\w*`, mas o `*` significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", o que quer dizer que se tiver uma `@` sozinha (sem nenhum caractere corresponde a `\w` depois), é retornado um *match* vazio. [Veja a diferença](https://ideone.com/lML4iw):

```
line <- 'Teste @ abc @REF1'

str_extract_all(line, "(?<=@)\\w+")
str_extract_all(line, "(?<=@)\\w*")
```

O primeiro retorna:

```
[1] "REF1"
```

E o segundo retorna:

```
[1] ""     "REF1"
```

---

Se quiser, pode ser mais específico (mas aí vai depender do formato exato da citação). Por exemplo, se o formato sempre for "3 letras maiúsculas e um dígito", então você pode usar:

```
str_extract_all(line, "(?<=@)[A-Z]{3}[0-9]")
```

Como não foram dados mais detalhes quanto ao formato, deixo apenas esta sugestão, mas o ideal é que você [seja o mais específico possível](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) para evitar falsos positivos.

Por exemplo, como `\w` também considera o caractere `_`, então o trecho `@___` é considerado válido ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/9VuwjI/1/)). Mas claro que se você "sabe" que esses casos não ocorrem com suas strings, não tem tanto problema usar `\w`. Tudo depende.

Comment: Obrigado! Para ser mais específico, eu sei que todas as citações são no formato @sobrenomeAnodePublicação: `@Vieira2019`. Então sei que os ultimas 4 dígitos serão números. Não sei se isso pode ajudar?!

Comment: @WillianVieira Neste caso poderia ser `"(?<=@)[A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4}"` (se terminar com exatamente 4 números, e com uma quantidade variada de letras).

Answer (score 3):

Com o modelo que você colocou consegui fazer assim.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#usando o tidyverse
citations <- str_extract_all(line, "@\\w*") %>% 
  as_vector() %>% 
  str_remove("@")

citations
#> [1] "REF1" "REF2" "REF3" "REF4" "REF5"

#R base
gregexpr(pattern = "@\\w*", text = line) %>% 
  regmatches(line, m = .) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  gsub("@","",.)
#> [1] "REF1" "REF2" "REF3" "REF4" "REF5"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Não há necessidade de usar o `stringr` nesse exercício. Podemos utilizar `regmatches` com `gregexpr`.

`regmatches` vai extrair as substrings que foram encontradas com `gregexpr` –essa última função encontra todas as sequências possíveis na string.

`regmatches` retornará uma `list` onde, nesse caso, o único objeto é um vetor com as substrings desejada. Então você fecha a expressão `regmatches(...)` em `unlist` para receber o resultado desejável.

Sobre a `pattern` que você deve usar, acredito que um modo mais fléxivel seja utilizando a POSIX class `[[:alnum:]]`. Esse tipo de classe corresponde a letras maiúsculas e minúsculas bem como números. Atente para o uso do parâmetro `pearl=TRUE` em `gregexpr`. Isso permite o uso de `[[:alnum:]]` como `pattern`. Também adicionamos quantificador `+` ao fim da `pattern`, que é um quantificador "greedy", ou seja, acha as substrings que tem letras e números em mais de uma vez sendo que o "match" é sempre para a maior substring possível. Por fim, usamos o *lookaround* tipo lookbehind `(?<=...)` para achar pedaços da string que comecem em `@` como já foi explicado nas respostas acima.

Portanto a solução fica assim:

```
unlist(regmatches(line, gregexpr("(?<=@)[[:alnum:]]+", line, perl = TRUE)))
```

O que retorna:

```
[1] "REF1" "REF2" "REF3" "REF4" "REF5"
```

Veja que essa solução é aproximadamente 5x mais rápida que `unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(...)`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base= unlist(regmatches(line, gregexpr("(?<=@)[[:alnum:]]+", line, perl = TRUE))),
  stringr = unlist(str_extract_all(line, "(?<=@)[[:alnum:]]+"))
)
```

Resultado:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    base  323.824  335.3105  381.1747  366.854  388.370 1300.399   100  a 
 stringr 1596.873 1632.4270 1772.1564 1666.888 1723.958 5634.818   100   b
```